# Retrofit single value / array

Tags: java, android, retrofit

this is my web service for sending and receiving a string value with key

**Urls.class**

```
public class Urls {
    public static final String MAIN_URL="example.com";
}
```

**API.class**

```
public interface API {

    @POST("user.php")
    Call<MainResponse> registerUser(@Body User user);

    @POST("user.php")
    Call<MainResponse>loginUser(@Body User user);

    @POST("contact.php")
    Call<MainResponse>checkNumber(@Body Phone phone);

}
```

**WebService.class**

```
    public class WebService {
    private static WebService instance;
    private API api;

    public WebService() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(Urls.MAIN_URL)
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

    public static WebService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WebService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public API getApi() {
        return api;
    }
}
```

**MainResponse.class**

```
public class MainResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;
}
```

**Phone.class**

```
public class Phone {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    public String phone;
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
            Phone phone=new Phone();
            phone.phone=contactsString[0];
            WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body().status==1){
                        //do something
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

My question is how to edit this to send an array filled with values `contactsString[]` and receive another array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service is in a way to get single request and give you back single response, you should change server side service if you are the backend developer of the service, to get a list of request and give back a list of result

this is your current service:

```
  @POST("contact.php")
Call<MainResponse>checkNumber(@Body Phone phone);
```

server side developer should change service for you to be able to send in body an object like this for Phones:

```
public class Phones {

@SerializedName("phones")
public List<String> phones;
}
```

and in your response you should get list of status and messages with request phones

response like this:

```
public class MainResponse {
public List<PhoneStatusResponse> phonesStatusList;

}

public class PhoneStatusResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    public int status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("phoneRequest")
    public String phone;

}
```

Comment: that is what I am asking for

Comment: you want to send an array of values as request and get the result. am I right?

Comment: I need to know what to edit in this code to change it to send array and receive an array

Comment: so I am telling you. because the retrofit request to the server is Async task and you don't have enough info in result to recognize for which request is, so you can not do that expect ask to change the service

Comment: all you are telling is about client side coding, you should change the service from server side

Comment: can you please show me it in code because I am confused

Comment: my friend is doing it on server I just want to edit my android code I am still not fully understand retrofit smoothly

Comment: my friend is doing it on server I just want to edit my android code I am still not fully understand retrofit smoothly

Comment: tyvm one last thing how to put response list in an array

Comment: was it helpful?

Comment: yea I will accept this but still one last step having some problems in MainResponse.class and in initializing values to an array in MainActivity